# Finding dim(Ker(A)) according to a given characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I was given this question:

[image: The given question]

1) a) is simple, the sum of the algebraic multiplicities is 6, so the matrix 6X6.

2) My problem is with b), how am i supposed to find the dimKerA?
What is the general idea? really stuck..

Thanks is advance

Comment: No additional information is given.. unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That $A$ is diagonalizable is key here. For instance, the characteristic polynomial of the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ is $\lambda^2$, but the dimension of its nullspace is 1, not 2.

Depending on how much theory you have covered, you can use the fact that a matrix is diagonalizable if and only if the dimension of the eigenspace is equal to the algebraic multiplicity of the corresponding eigenvalue in the characteristic polynomial. For $\lambda = 0$, the eigenspace is the same as the nullspace.

Or here is a more detailed explanation if you have not covered that theorem. Since $A$ is diagonalizable, there is a diagonal matrix $D$ such that $D = P^{-1}AP$. You probably know that the diagonal entries of $D$ are exactly the eigenvalues of $A$. It is clear, then, that $dim(Ker(D)) = 2$. So we just want to prove that $dim(Ker(D)) = dim(Ker(A))$.

Well, suppose the column vectors $\textbf{v},\textbf{w} \in Ker(D)$, are two basis vectors of $ker(D)$. So they are nonzero and linearly independent. Also

$$
P^{-1}AP\textbf{v} = \textbf{0} \Longleftrightarrow AP\textbf{v} = P\textbf{0} = \textbf{0},
$$

and similarly for $\textbf{w}$. Thus $P\textbf{v},P\textbf{w}  \in Ker(A),$ and since $P$ is invertible $P\textbf{v}$ and $P\textbf{w}$ are nonzero and linearly independent. So we know that $dim(Ker(A)) \geq 2$. Suppose $dim(Ker(A)) > 2$. Then there exists $\textbf{b} \in Ker(A)$, nonzero and linearly independent from $P\textbf{v}$, and $P\textbf{w}$. Since $P$ is invertible, $P^{-1}\textbf{b}, \textbf{v}, \textbf{w}$ are also linearly independent, and you can check by a similar calculation as above that $P^{-1}\textbf{b} \in Ker(D)$, which is a contradiction, since $dim(Ker(D)) = 2$.

Comment: We didn't cover in class the first theorem, but the second expanation was great, thanks

Comment: It would probably only be covered in a very rigorous introductory linear algebra course. You're welcome.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $\lambda=0$ is an eigen value of the matrix with multiplicity $2$. $\dim \ker(A)$ is same as nullity of $A$. What can you say about the nullity of $A$?

Comment: nullity is the same as dimKet right?
if the algebraic multi is 2, the the dimKer(A) is also 2?

Comment: Yes @MichaelSegal

Comment: Yes, that is what "dim ker(A) is the same as nullity of A" MEANS!

Comment: How can i explain it? if the a.m of 0 is 2 then why is the dimKer(a) also 2?